# Tiled2Unity produces white meshes over correct mesh's

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, tiled

I have a tiled project:
[image: Tiled]

And I have Tiled2Unity 1.0.10.1 with the Tiled project loaded and newest Tiled2Uinty scripts imported to my project.
If I click "preview map" this shows up:
[image: tiled2unity perfect map]

But this is how it looks in Unity:

[image]

Note I deliberately navigated to the relevant mesh's directory although I used the generated prefab in the scene

Does anyone have any ideas what is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you've got at least one error to deal with (See the bottom of your screenshot: MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'SortingLayerExposed' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. ").

I don't know what would be causing that exception but I would open your console window in Unity and re-export to see if there are some other errors or warnings that may tell you what has gone wrong for you. I try my best to print out any problems that may have occurred while importing a Tiled map into Unity.